# How does cross-sectional area affect electric field?

Tags: electric-fields

Does electric field (electric field strength) depends upon the area of electrodes (considering both electrodes are same area)

And what if the size of electrodes are not same?

Answer (score 0):

The electric field in the vicinity of two objects which are charged as a result of being connected to the terminals of a battery will depend on their size, shape, and voltage, as well as the nature of any other materials in their vicinity.

Answer (score 0):

> Does electric field (electric field strength) depends upon the area of
> electrodes (considering both electrodes are same area)

For two uniformly oppositely charged surfaces, the electric field, and therefore the field strength, will be the same (uniform) between the surfaces independent of the area. See Figure 1. The strength of the electric field between the plates is proportional to the density of the electric field lines.

> And what if the size of electrodes are not same?

It will depend on the shape of the electrodes. Fig 2 shows the electric field between a point electrode and a planar electrode. Fig 3 shows the electric between two point electrodes. Note that the electric field strength (density of the field lines) is greatest near the point electrodes.

Hope this helps.

[image]